# Как сделать обязательным/необязательным для заполнения одно поле в зависимости от значения другого Drupal в форме регистрации

Tags: php, drupal

Ниже пример кода, который делает первое поле необязательным для заполнения в самой форме

```
<?php
    function мой_модуль_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    $form['field_website']['und'][0]['#required'] = FALSE;
    //вот так поле становится необязательным для заполненияв самой форме
    }
?>

$form['test']['und'][0]['value']=test;
```

Но мне нужно чтобы после отправки формы происходила проверка содержимого в другом поле, и если оно совпадает с нужным значением "test", то первое поле становилось необязательным.

```
if($form['test']['und'][0]['value']=='test'){
    $form['field_website']['und'][0]['#required'] = FALSE;
}
```

пробовал использовать function form_submit но даже не знаю то это или не то, но на отправку формы она не повлияла.